# $urlRouteProvider, simple routing

Tags: angular-ui-router

Can't get my head around $urlRouterPovider...

basically whenever I go to a link it should load associated view and controller. So that works.
        $urlRouterProvider.when("/","/home")
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/error")

```
     $stateProvider.state('views', {
        url: "/:view",
        templateUrl: function(stateParams, formResolver) {
          return "views/" + stateParams.view + "/" + stateParams.view + "-view.html";
        },
        controllerProvider: function($stateParams) {
              return "" + $stateParams.view + "Ctrl";
        }
     });
```

So whenever user goes to `http://localhost:3030/#/foo`, it loads "views/foo/foo.html" with controller as "fooCtrl", and goes to `home` by default, and for all other cases `errror`.

That is cool. What I need though, whenever user goes to `http://localhost:3030/#/auth` it would redirect to "/auth" on the server, skipping stateProvider. Currently it sees that as a state and tries to find corresponding view and controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to redirect them to the server you need to leave out the #/ part of the URL.

The browser ignores the the #/ portion of the URL, which is how AngularJS is able to allow the page you server from localhost:3030/#/ handle the request. This is essentially still just requesting localhost:3030/

If you are wanting to do a true redirect or navigation to /auth on your server, ignore state for that request - you want your browser to make a straight-up HTTP request pointed directly at your server. Use /auth as the action in your form, or post to /auth from within your controller. When you are done on the server, redirect the user back to your Angular application.

Remember as well that you need to have some mechanism for your AngularJS application to know ehnIn our applications, we have the server set a cookie with a JWT token in it that is then used by the AngularJS application to retrieve the user information. This way the AngularJS application knows how to tell when a the user is really logged in (vs. a user going to a URL that represents a logged-in state).